# How to pass a string variable in BULK LOAD command in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to pass the file name as a variable in SQL BULK load. But I am getting a syntax error. If someone can help that will be great. Below is the code that I wrote.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML,@File VARCHAR(200)
SELECT @File='C:\xyz.xml'
SELECT @XML= CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @File, SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
```

I can not hardcode @File like  BULK 'C:\xyz.xml' as the file name will change frequently.

Comment: Opps!!! i have changed tag. Sorry for wrong tagging .. @Hobbo

Answer (score 3):

You can't parametrise it. So use dynanic SQL

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @File VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SET @File='C:\xyz.xml';
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @XML= CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @File + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml', @XML;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. i was totally hopeless. But I needed to edit the answer. but still 1+ :) @gbn

Answer (score 0):

Editing your answer as it was not giving @XML value

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @File VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SET @File='C:\xyz.xml';
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @XML_OUT= CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @File     + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml OUT', @XML_OUT=@XML OUTPUT;
```